# How To run Gedit and Subl commands in the background?

Tags: command-line, gedit

If I use Gedit or Subl (sublime text) commands in the terminal to open a file, I can't do anything else in the terminal until I close the text editor. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Opening gedit in background should allow you to use the terminal

> `gedit &`

Hope you know this .

Comment: In that case `&` is unnecessary isn't it?

Comment: @seriousdev to make it run in background you need `&`

Comment: Well I thought you were implying that the user opens gedit first, my bad.

Comment: One issue... after issuing the command with &, it opens the text editor in the background. Then, I save the text and close the editor. Now if I enter another command in the same window, it will show something like this at the end : [1]+  Done                    subl a.txt

Comment: Once a process is completed it will just throw a message on terminal saying **Done**

Answer (score 5):

Use `setsid`, which runs a program in a new session; for example:

```
setsid gedit
```

Also you can close terminal and `gedit` will stay running.

Answer (score 3):

If you've started the editor already, you can send it to the background as if you had started it via

> gedit &

in the first place:

Return to the blocked terminal, and press `CTRL` - `Z`.
Notice that the terminal is now usable, but the program is now suspended.

Enter `bg` on that terminal to make it run again, and enjoy the unblocked terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding different kind of approach:

You could also use a terminal that supports multiples tabs at once.
Here are some examples: Gnome Terminal (the one that comes preinstalled on Ubuntu), Guake, Terminator, Tilda etc

Shortcut: CTRL + Shift + T = almost always the create new tab shortcut